# KeyVaultErrorException : too many requests

Tags: .net, azure

I am getting below error during access the azure keyvault (configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault) -

Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: 'Request was not processed because too many requests were received. Reason: VaultOperationLimitReached'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service limits in Key Vault prevent misuse of resources and ensure quality of service for all Key Vault's clients. When a service threshold is exceeded, Key Vault limits any further requests from that client for a period of time, returns `HTTP status code 429` **(Too many requests)**, and the request fails. Failed requests that return a 429 do not count towards the throttle limits tracked by Key Vault.

Key Vault is designed to use store and retrieve your secrets at deployment time. In recent times Key Vault is being used at run-time to store and retrieve secrets, and often apps and services want to use Key Vault like a database. Current limits do not support high throughput rates.

Key Vault was originally created with the limits specified in [Azure Key Vault service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-limits). To maximize your Key Vault throughput rates, here are some recommended guidelines/best practices for maximizing your throughput:

check here [how does key vault handle its limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-throttling#how-does-key-vault-handle-its-limits)

How to throttle your app in response to service limits [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-throttling#how-to-throttle-your-app-in-response-to-service-limits)

Please have a look for more info [The danger of using config addazurekeyvault in net core](https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2019/07/29/the-danger-of-using-config-addazurekeyvault-in-net-core/)